# Why added mouseover effect on div the effect persist even after mouseout?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, javascript-objects

What I mean is how to retain actual previous class on mouse out?

```js
function highlight( x, y) {

  var sel=document.getElementById(y);

  sel.style.borderBottom= "2px solid "+x;
  sel.style.opacity="1";
  sel.style.transition="all ease-in .1s"

}
```

The transition still remain even after mouse out I need the old CSS class on mouse out.

Comment: Calling a function onMouseOver doesn't mean the inverse function will happen onMouseOut. To recover the previous state simply make a temporary copy of it onMouseOver, and set it back onMouseOut.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually setting styles 'forever' to your element: `sel.style.opacity = 1`.
Try adding to your element some css hover logic, something like:

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  background-color: red;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='box'>Your element</div>
```